# Enabled KeepAlive, number of Apache httpd processes shot through the roof

Tags: apache-2.2

We have a server that has been running for quite a while with KeepAlive off. I thought we'd get a noticeable performance boost by enabling KeepAlive, but as soon as I did, the number of httpd processes skyrocketed from 30+ to 200+. I've never seen this behavior before from enabling KeepAlive.

This is on CentOS 5 with Apache 2.2.3.

I have done much googling and have not found anything related to this. Any suggestions on where else to look or what to try are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the connections are being held open longer, and so other apaches are being run to accept new requests.  What clients are connecting to apache, and maybe you can tune down how long apache will try and hold the connection open.

Comment: I've got Timeout at the standard 120, and KeepAliveTimeout at 6. What directive controls how long Apache holds the connection open for? But this behavior still seems very strange.

Comment: @danielj `KeepAliveTimeout` determines that.  Are you sure nothing else changed?  Which MPM are you using, and what are its limits set to?

Comment: I am using prefork with the defaults. I changed KeepAliveTimeout to 3 seconds, and while I think 6 would be more optimal, I am happy with the results with 3 seconds - definitely an improvement. Thank you for your assistance.